# Form submit not triggered .Net core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to make a form where you can choose which ingredients to put onto your pizza. I've created a pizzamodel class which contains all the different props you can put on your pizza. This class is bound to a pagemodel so that it can be altered by a form in the pageview. When setting the asp-for propreties on the inputs in the pageview the IDE autocompletes it so i would assume that the pizzamodel is succesfully connected to the pagemodel and view. But when i click the submit button on the form nothing happens. normally even without handling the post you should see the page refreshing.

The projects file structure

[image]

This is the pizza model

```
namespace Pizzeria.Models
{
    public class PizzasModel
    {
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string PizzaName { get; set; }
        public float BasePrice { get; set; }
        public bool TomatoSauce { get; set; }
        public bool Tuna { get; set; }
        public bool Pineapple { get; set; }
        public bool Beef { get; set; }
        public bool Ham { get; set; }
        public bool Mushroom { get; set; } 
        public bool Peperoni { get; set; }
        public bool Cheese { get; set; }
        public float FinalPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the pagemodel

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Pizzeria.Models;

namespace Pizzeria.Pages.Forms
{
    public class CustomPizzaModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public PizzasModel Pizza { get; set; }
        public float PizzaPrice { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            PizzaPrice = Pizza.BasePrice;

            if (Pizza.TomatoSauce) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Cheese) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Peperoni) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Tuna) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Pineapple) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Ham) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Beef) PizzaPrice += 1;
            if (Pizza.Mushroom) PizzaPrice += 1;

            return RedirectToAction("/Checkout/Checkout", new {Pizza.PizzaName, PizzaPrice});
        }
    }
}
```

This is the pageview

```
@page
@model Pizzeria.Pages.Forms.CustomPizzaModel
@{
}

<div class="text-center container">
    <h1 class="main-text">Create your own pizza!</h1>
    <from method="POST" class="form-container"> 
        <input type="text" asp-for="Pizza.PizzaName" placeholder="Give your pizza a name..." />

        <div class="input">
            <label>Tomato Sauce</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.PizzaName" placeholder="Tomato Sauce" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Beef</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Beef" placeholder="Beef" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Tuna</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Tuna" placeholder="Tuna" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Mushrooms</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Mushroom" placeholder="Mushrooms" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Pineapple</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Pineapple" placeholder="Pineapple" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Cheese</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Cheese" placeholder="Cheese" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Peperoni</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Peperoni" placeholder="Peperoni" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Ham</label>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Pizza.Ham" placeholder="Ham" />
        </div>
  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Order my Pizza</button>
    </from>
</div>
```

Comment: You appear to have a <from> tag instead of a <form> tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form or from this is the question ...

Comment: 5 hours of pain and suffering....